# Right to Left (RTL) Tiles

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, right-to-left

Is it possible to create an Right to Left (RTL) tile for Windows 8 apps?

The tiles switch to RTL direction when one changes the windows settings but I need to force it even on non-RTL machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tile or toast notifications, setting the [`lang`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212857.aspx) attribute to an RTL language (e.g., "ar-SA") on either the `<binding />` or `<visual/>` element in the notification XML will perform layout appropriate for the specified language.

Answer (score 1):

See this MSDN article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj712702.aspx
You should be able to use UnicodeDirectionMarkers.LeftToRightDirectionMarker to mark the text and reverse it.